# What should we do about language tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have [french](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french), [japanese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese), [english](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [nepalese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nepalese), and  [chinese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese). I can understand [latin](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) as it's a family of languages, but why are the other ones here? This site is a site about language acquisition in general, so most if not all specific language tagged questions would be off-topic.

Should we burninate these tags and make sure no new ones come up, or should we keep them on the off-chance that someone comes up with a specific language question that's not off-topic?

Comment: Given that [it hasn't been settled whether language-specific questions are on-topic](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-individual-languages-on-topic), this question is pointless at this time.

Comment: @Gilles I personally think this is a perfectly valid question to ask. I can understand all of these potential tags except for [tag:nepalese] as it's such an isolated and uncommon language.

Comment: Why do you consider Latin a "family of languages" but not Chinese, for example?

Comment: @Nathaniel, I do not claim to be an expert in languages. I see what you mean in that Chinese is a family of languages. Should I edit?

Comment: My main point is that Latin is a language like English or German.  It has changed over the years, but so do all long-lived languages.

Comment: I understand that Latin is also a language, but you also say that French and Spanish are "Latin-based languages". Should there be a new tag for latin-based, germanic-based, semetic-based, etc?

Answer (score 12):

We should keep these tags and use them on questions that are about learning a specific language.

Comment: But isn't learning a specific language off-topic? Or only English as there's another site for it?

Comment: We've already agreed that asking questions about a specific language is off-topic as it's unlikely to come in use to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 3):

We should keep this tags, but change how they're used. For one, since specific language questions are off-topic here, we **should not** use these tags in these types of questions. These tags should only be reserved for questions that pertain to these languages, but only when these questions can be applied to many different situations.