# Can we get rid of [nepalese]?

Tags: discussion

Honestly, I've no idea why we even have [nepalese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nepalese). As discussed [here](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-should-we-do-about-language-tags), specific language questions should still use specific language tags, but I just don't see anyone posting a specific question about the Nepalese language. As of right now, there are no questions using this tag, and I can't imagine many questions in the future either, seeing as how this is not a widely spoken language. Can we give this tag the axe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a tag has no posts, it will automatically be removed by the roomba (empty tag deletion script). There's no need to manually delete the tag.